¿Cómo puedo mostrar las columnas con espacio entre ellas de manera correcta según el dispositivo?
Tengo el siguiente código elaborado con Bootstrap 5 y funciona bien sin el gap-3, al agregarlo no logro lo que requiero:
<div class="container my-5">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap gap-3">
        <div class="card col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12">
          <div class="card-body">
            This is some text within a card body.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12">
          <div class="card-body">
            This is some text within a card body 2.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12">
          <div class="card-body">
            This is some text within a card body 3.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12">
          <div class="card-body">
            This is some text within a card body 4.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12">
          <div class="card-body">
            This is some text within a card body 5.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12">
          <div class="card-body">
            This is some text within a card body 6.
          </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>

Si le quito el gap-3 se muestra como deseo según el tamaño de la pantalla, pero requiero darle espacios entre una card y otra.

Intenta realizando este cambio,en Bootstrap 5 no se incluye nativamente una clase llamada gap-3.
En su lugar prueba este codigo.
<div class="container my-5">
    <div class="row gx-3 gy-3">
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    This is some text within a card body.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    This is some text within a card body 2.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    This is some text within a card body 3.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    This is some text within a card body 4.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    This is some text within a card body 5.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    This is some text within a card body 6.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Saludos

Muchas gracias! Funciona perfectamente!
